# When and where are periods allowed in C function definition parameter lists?

Tags: c, visual-c++, standards, syntax-error

In the [PGP 6.5.8 source code](https://github.com/ysangkok/pgp-win32-6.5.8/blob/master/libs/pfl/common/pgpMemoryMgrStd.c#L83) I see a function defined like this:

```
static void
sUnlockMemory(
void *  mem,
PGPSize numBytes.
PGPBoolean  nonPageable )
{
/* we always call VirtualLock() so always call VirtualUnlock() */
(void)wasLocked;

VirtualUnlock ( mem, numBytes );
}
```

Note the period in the end of line 4. What does it do? Can I substitute it with a comma? The file is marked last modified August 1999. Build instructions reference Visual C++ 6.

I put it unmodified on Github but it can be downloaded here too: http://www.pgpi.org/products/pgp/versions/freeware/win32/6.5.8/

Comment: That is a bug, will not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, the only time you can have periods in a function prototype is when the function accepts a  variable number of arguments, and that is always specified with three dots as the last parameter declaration. Any other use of a dot between the parentheses is a syntax error.

E.g.:

void fn(int arg1, ...);

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a syntax error.

That code is enabled only if `PGP_WIN32` is defined, though I doubt that that's relevant; I'm sure code that doesn't compile on Windows wouldn't be released.

The PGP software is now owned by Symantec, which makes the source code [available only for peer review](http://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/symantec-pgp-desktop-peer-review-source-code). I wonder if they've deliberately introduced trivial syntax errors to make the source code difficult to use while leaving it easy to review. (But the license agreement appears to allow you to compile the code.)